# All Ruby commands immediately close

Tags: ruby

I did a fresh install of Ruby 2.6.5 x86 on my Windows Server 2016 64-bit machine (previously had 64-bit 2.6.5 and some 2.4.5 version. Can't remember if it was 32/64 bit). I did NOT run the MSYS install at the end. I see the PATH has been updated to include ruby. When I type ruby in a command prompt nothing happens. I do not get a message saying ruby is unrecognized. It actually looks like ruby is going to open (I see mouse loading animation) in the command prompt but then immediately terminates. How do I fix this?[image: CMD]

[image: PATH]

As requested here are the results of `where ruby`:
[image: where ruby]

Comment: Type `where ruby`, to get an idea of what it is actually trying to run. Paste result into the question.

Comment: @Casper I added the output to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

```
ruby
```

is not interactive interpreter, it is only used to run complete scripts like this:

```
ruby script.rb
```

Use

```
irb
```

for interactive programming. You also can run a script and then poke around inside it with

```
irb -r ./script.rb
```

Comment: Hi. What you posted is correct but is not solution to my issue. If you see in the OP I cannot even output the version of ruby I have installed. If that doesn't work the irb will not either.